# How to securely deploy php mysql application pre packaged with linux (CentOS)?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, deployment, centos

I have a PHP aapplication and it works in intranet. Now everytime when I want to install this application on my clients machine, I have to install CentOS on one of his system. Then I do lot many configurations. However some days back one of my friend told me that it is possible to package the application with CentOS with all configurations pre-defined. And I can also define that no changes will happen in system other then root user, and I can set root user information at my end anc can give a secondry user ID to my client for other operation.

But after searching for a while, I am not really sure on how exactly to do this. Just wanted to have a brief guideline from you fellows and wanted to get some definite and professional start on the topic.

I will really appriciate your help.

Regards. And Happy Holi :)

Answer (score 0):

Try "clonezilla" to make a copy of your existing OS with existing configuration and you can deploy it on your client machine.